# app to receive text and return a number

Tags: php, apache

I need to set up a server that will accept some text from my app then return a number/code to the app. The number should then be able to be used to retrieve the text that was originally sent to the server.

```
App                                      Server
                Text. ->
                <- number

                     OR

                Number ->
                <- text
```

I'm really not sure how to start with this, so my question is, How should I go about this? And how should I get started? My knowledge of this sort of server implementation is quite limited.

This is how I'd imagine it would work:
Apache server?
Php script to read text/ generate code to send back

App would send/receive data using POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes will use Post.

You need to store text in database and generate a random number and store this number along with text in database as well as  send  same number in response. These numbers can be used for getting respective text stored in database.

Let me know if this is what you were expecting. If you want some code sample let me know.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking Alfred. I also need to know what I'd need to install on the server to get this to work. Apache? PHP? MySQL? 
Some basic code would help if you think you can throw some together quickly.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, this is quite a bit more complex that I had thought. So here's the second pass at this problem. As you stated your app is going to `GET` or `POST` information to your web server a string that it should store and give back a key. To do this, I feel the quickest way is to use a flat file, where each line is the index of the string.

```
<?php
    define('FILEDB', 'str.db');

    # Check if the file is there.
    if (!file_exists(FILEDB))
        die('No Such File.');

    $file = file(FILEDB);

    if (is_numeric($_POST['key']))
    {   # We want to get a string.

        # Check that file index is set.
        if (!isset($file[$_POST['key']]))
            die('File index not set.');

        # Output string & End.
        die($file[$_POST['key']]);
    }

    # Save new string to file database.
    file_put_contents(FILEDB, implode(PHP_EOL, $file) . PHP_EOL . $_POST['key']);

    # Output string & End.
    die(count($file) + 1);

?>
```